How large can the set of turbulent points be?
This question resisted attempts on MSE.
Let $E \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a Lebesgue measurable set. We say that $x \in \mathbb R^n$ is a turbulent point of E if both the following conditions hold:
$$\liminf_{r \to 0_+} \frac{|E \cap B_r (x)|}{|B_r (x)|} = 0$$
$$\limsup_{r \to 0_+}\frac{|E \cap B_r (x)|}{|B_r (x)|} = 1.$$
In other words, the density of $E$ oscillates maximally between $0$ and $1$.
How large can this set be? More specifically,
Question: What is the supremal Hausdorff dimension of the set of turbulent points of a subset of $\mathbb R^n$? And is the supremum achieved?

Presumably $| \cdot |$ denotes Lebesgue measure, and $B_r(x)$ is a ball of radius $r$ centred at $x$, but you should say so.

Naive question: what can be said about the Hausdorff dimension of the set where lower and upper densities differ?

@PavelGubkin Also a good question… I feel it might be significantly bigger dimension wise, even equal to $n$ possibly. I will be chewing on this today haha.

The Hausdorff dimension of the turbulent points can be $n.$
For $n=1$ (the reals), this is a consequence of the proof of Theorem 1 in On Lebesgue’s density theorem by Casper Goffman (1950):

THEOREM 1. If $Z$ is any set of measure $0,$ there is a measurable set $S$ whose metric density does not exist at any point of $Z.$

Remark 1: An examination of Goffman's proof shows that he actually proved the stronger result that each point of $Z$ is a turbulent point of $S.$ Moreover, the construction by Goffman shows that $S$ can be an $F_{\sigma}$ set. Note that we're not claiming the set of turbulent points of $S$ is equal to $Z.$ Indeed, the former is a Borel set (surely in Borel class $3,$ if not actually in Borel class $2),$ and $Z$ can be a non-Borel set.
Remark 2: Goffman's result (turbulent point version) holds more generally for ${\mathbb R}^n,$ but I don't recall to what extent modifications of his proof might be needed. Thus, in ${\mathbb R}^n$ the Hausdorff dimension can be $n.$
Remark 3: Goffman uses non-centered (i.e. not necessarily symmetric) density, and thus his result is weaker than the corresponding result for centered/symmetric Lebesgue density, since we have $0 \; \leq \; \underline{d} \; \leq \; \underline{d^{s}} \; \leq \; \overline{d^{s}} \; \leq \; \overline{d} \; \leq \; 1$ where $d$ & $d^{s}$ refer to non-centered & centered/symmetric Lebesgue density notions. However, Christian Remling showed in this mathoverflow answer that Goffman's result can be strengthened to centered Lebesgue density in ${\mathbb R}^n.$ Other discussions related to this are given in this Mathematics SE answer and this 21 November 2006 sci.math post.

That is an extremely surprising result. Thank you for the answer and resources!
